# Unexpected Token when trying to import a Vue component to test it with Ava

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, ava

I have a `Nuxt` project containing a test file under `test/index.test.js` and I'm trying to test individual components by mounting them like so:

```
import { Index } from './../pages/Index.vue'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

test.beforeEach(() => {
    const wrapper = mount(Index)
    console.log('Wrapper: ' + wrapper)
}
```

Which gives me the following error when running the `ava` command line:

```
SyntaxError: /weather-app/pages/Index.vue: Unexpected token (1:0)
1 | <template>
```

How may I test individual components and their methods using the `Ava` test runner? What's the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried importing Index as default? I've imported pages for consumption on other pages and I had alway done it using the default import:
`import Index from './../pages/Index.vue'

Comment: It does not solve the problem sadly, the issue seems to be linked to babel's transpiling of my vue components

Comment: That makes sense, I should have read in closer. I think the big issue you're facing is that Nuxt is an integrated and end-to-end solution but you're attempting to unit test only the front-end component. Are you opposed to running tests the way Nuxt.js suggests in their example with Ava? (https://nuxtjs.org/examples/testing)